# error when setting correct resolution after install Nvidia 340 drivers

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

I have ubuntu 14.04 and installed the recommended driver for Nvidia but resolution still 1360x768 which I need to change to 1920x1080

here is driver I installed

[image]

Xrandr values below

```
mohamed@mohamed-Work:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0*    59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

what I did is creating new mode like this

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

then adding new mode like this

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1920x1080_60.00
```

but I got an error below

```
mohamed@mohamed-Work:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1920x1080_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

and my xorg.conf file listed below

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: builtin, VertRefresh source: builtin
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    ModeLine       "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1360x768" 72.000 1360 1408 1440 1520 768 771 781 790 +hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1152x864" 81.620 1152 1216 1336 1520 864 865 868 895 -hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 50.000 800 856 976 1040 600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "680x384" 36.000 680 704 720 760 384 385 390 395 +hsync -vsync doublescan
    ModeLine       "640x480" 25.175 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "512x384" 32.500 512 524 592 672 384 385 388 403 -hsync -vsync doublescan
    ModeLine       "400x300" 25.000 400 428 488 520 300 318 321 333 +hsync +vsync doublescan
    ModeLine       "320x240" 12.587 320 328 376 400 240 245 246 262 -hsync -vsync doublescan
    ModeLine       "nvidia-auto-select" 65.000 1024 1048 1184 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 1800"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    Option "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes, NoVirtualSizeCheck, NoMaxPClkCheck, NoWidthAlignmentCheck, NoExtendedGpuCapabilitiesCheck"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: What is your graphics card?

Comment: Nvidia Quadro FX1800

Comment: As per the nvidia site you are using the right driver for your graphics card. But the one you are using is proprietary. If you want you can give nvidia open source driver a try. I don't know about the driver in your particular case but you can google it. Moreover as per the data that you have provided by default with the proprietary driver you are getting 1360x768 with 60 refresh rate. Anything lower than 60 refresh rate is not that good. Moreover it might be the hardware limitation of your monitor also? What is the best resolution and at what refresh it can support?

Comment: I am using the open source driver and using xrandr to change resolution to native (1920x1080) but I got system freeze when just selecting text in writer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in this [link](https://brainwreckedtech.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/howto-get-nvidia-on-linux-to-use-custom-resolutions-over-dvi/)

Open the file xorg.conf like this

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

edit the section device to be like in the link above